# Using Mathematica to solve a probability problem

Tags: probability-or-statistics

The problem is from *Principles of Statistics* by M.G. Bulmer:

> In a certain survey of the work of chemical research workers, it was found, on the basis of extensive data, that on average each man required no fume cupboard for 60 per cent of his time, one cupboard for 30 per cent and two cupboards for 10 per cent; three or more were never required. If a group of four chemists worked independently of one another, how many fume cupboards should be available in order to provide adequate facilities for at least 95 per cent of the time?

My approach to solving it has been to enumerate, for the 4 chemists, all the cases in which each requires 0, 1 or 2 fume cupboards.  This takes the form of a list like so:

```
{{0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,1}, {0,0,0,2}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,0,1,1}, {0,0,2,0},...}
```

I then compute the probability of each particular case, sort the cases from low to high by number of cupboards required, and finally compute a running cumulative probability:

```
(* enumerate all the cases, as length-4, base-3 numbers *)
hoods = PadLeft[IntegerDigits[#, 3], 4, 0] & /@ Range[0, 80];

(* compute overall odds per case *)
odds = {0 -> 0.6, 1 -> 0.3, 2 -> 0.1};
data = Table[{
    Plus @@ x, x, x /. odds, Times @@ (x /. odds)}, 
    {x, hoods}];

(* sort by number of hoods needed for each case *)
data = Sort[data, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &];

(* compute & thread in cumulative probability the N hoods will be enough *)
cumulativeOdds = Accumulate[#[[4]] & /@ data];
data = Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Thread@{Range[1, 81], cumulativeOdds, data};

headings = {"idx", "cum. prob.", "hoods needed", 
   "hoods per chemist", "prob./chemist", "overall prob."};

Grid[Prepend[data, headings], Frame -> All, 
    Background -> {None, {51 -> LightRed}}, Spacings -> {1.5, 1.2}]
```

[image: table top]

[image: table middle]

My question is: is there a more direct way to approach this kind problem, perhaps using higher-level *Mathematica* features/functions or higher-level concepts from probability?

Followup:

I made a table and graph summarizing Eric Towers' Excellently Simple & Short Solution:

```
pdf = CoefficientList[(0.6 + 0.3 x + 0.1 x^2)^4, x];
cdf = Accumulate[pdf]; len = Length[pdf];
tbl = Table[{i - 1, pdf[[i]], cdf[[i]]}, {i, 1, len}];
Grid[{{tbl // TableForm, ListPlot[Transpose@tbl[[All, {2, 3}]],
    AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0}, DataRange -> {0, len - 1}, 
    ImageSize -> 250]}}, Spacings -> 4]
```

[image: table and plot]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[b + 2 c, {a, b, c} \[Distributed] 
                               MultinomialDistribution[4, {.6, .3, .1}]];

Reduce[CDF[dist, x] >= .95, x]

(* x>=4 *)
```

Check:

```
CDF[dist, 4]
(* .9585 *)
```

The PMF:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 8}, ExtentSize -> All, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Explanation:

```
MultinomialDistribution[4, {.6, .3, .1}]
```

Defines the base distribution - we're taking 4 samples (the four participants) from a distribution with each having a .6/.3/.1 probability of getting catagory 1/2/3 (corresponding to none, 1, and 2 hoods needed).

```
TransformedDistribution[b + 2 c, {a, b, c} \[Distributed] 
                                   MultinomialDistribution[4, {.6, .3, .1}]];
```

takes this into an algebra on the random variable (we'll get some number of category 1 (a) worth zero, some number of category 2 (b) worth 1, and some number of category 3 (c) worth 2) - so 0*a+1*b+2*c hoods total for some realization of the variable. The 0*a is obviously 0, so the sum we're after is simply b+2c. The `TransformedDistribution` gives us that sum, itself a random variable.

```
Reduce[CDF[dist, x] >= .95, x]
```

solves for where in the distribution the Cumulative Distribution Function (the probability for all realizations of *x* *at or below something*) is >=.95, our desired threshold. *N.b.*: This appears to be one of those cases where the more typical `Quantile` or `InverseCDF` returns unevaluated - MMA does not handle this particular transform for those, so `Reduce` fills those shoes.

And, in the spirit of *"... higher-level concepts from probability..."* (though I'd venture it's a stretch to call this such), a direct appeal to the multinomial expansion:

```
Table[{n, N@Tr@Select[CoefficientRules[(.3 o + .1 t + .6 z)^4], 
                  Total[#[[1]]*{1, 2, 0}] <= n &][[All, 2]]}, {n, 0, 8}]

(*
{{0,0.1296},{1,0.3888},{2,0.6696},{3,0.864},
 {4,0.9585},{5,0.9909},{6,0.9987},{7,0.9999},{8,1.}}
*)
```

Or, by convolution of the PMF:

```
Accumulate@Nest[ListConvolve[#, {.6, .3, .1}, {1, -1}, 0] &, {.6, .3, .1}, 3]

(* {0.1296,0.3888,0.6696,0.864,0.9585,0.9909,0.9987,0.9999,1.} *)
```

The same (convolution), but appealing to the *Fourier Transform*, so we need not nest explicitly (and depending on the problem, can have great performance benefits):

```
ps = {.6, .3, .1};
num = 4;
asize = 2^Ceiling[Log2[num]*(Length@ps - 1)];
padded = PadRight[ps, asize];
fourier = Sqrt[asize] Fourier[padded];
Accumulate@TakeWhile[Chop@InverseFourier[fourier^num]/Sqrt[asize], # != 0 &]

(* {0.1296,0.3888,0.6696,0.864,0.9585,0.9909,0.9987,0.9999,1.} *)
```

I suppose a "higher level concept" might be complex probabilities, so for complete LOLs, here's the result using them combined with the [*Poisson-Binomial Distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) (I won't clutter with code, *pbpmf2* is just the referenced distribution, with an additional argument of the weights (4 each))

```
pbpmf2[{a, b} /. Solve[a + b - 2 a b == 3/10 && a*b == 1/10, {a, b}] //
         First, {4, 4}] // Accumulate // N // Chop

(* {0.1296,0.3888,0.6696,0.864,0.9585,0.9909,0.9987,0.9999,1.} *)
```

Another way would be using a *Markov Chain*:

```
mc = PadRight[
   Join[PadLeft[{.6, .3, .1}, #] & /@ 
     Range[3, 9], {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1}}]];

dmc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, mc];

Table[{n - 1, CDF[dmc[4], n]}, {n, 1, Length@mc}]

(* {{0,0.1296},{1,0.3888},{2,0.6696},{3,0.864},{4,0.9585},{5,0.9909},{6,0.9987},{7,0.9999},{8,1}} *)
```

Finally, in the spirit of *"... higher-level Mathematica features/functions..."*, the result via our own distribution definition:

```
dz = ProbabilityDistribution[
   Piecewise[{{.6, x == 0}, {.3, x == 1}, {.1, x == 2}}], {x, 0, 2, 1}];

dx = ProductDistribution[{dz, 4}];

Table[{n, Probability[user1 + user2 + user3 + user4 <= n, 
                     {user1, user2, user3, user4} \[Distributed] dx]}, {n, 0, 8}]

(*
{{0,0.1296},{1,0.3888},{2,0.6696},{3,0.864},
 {4,0.9585},{5,0.9909},{6,0.9987},{7,0.9999},{8,1.}}
*)
```

Comment: An explanation would be appreciated by ignoramuses like me.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: we can start with `MultinomialDistribution[4, {.6, .3, .1}]`: the second argument is the list of probabilities given in the problem, and you are asking about the four chemists. The `Reduce[]` answers when the probability will be 0.95 or greater. (One could also have used `InverseCDF[dist, 0.95]` of course, before rounding.)

Comment: @J.M. That much *seemed* apparent but I am baffled by `b + 2 c` here.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, would it help if I wrote it as `0*a + 1*b + 2*c`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: done, and ninja'd by J.M.

Comment: @J.M. Oh.  Heh.  I should Destroy All Evidence but I'll leave it for other people's amusement instead. :^)

Comment: Ah, `Quantile[]`/`InverseCDF[]` doesn't work… damn, that's another bug on my *gedanken* version… :D

Comment: Well, explanation  appreciated!

Comment: The style of the `ListConvolve` method appeals to me.  Wish I could +1 again for that.

Comment: I quite like the last one; not much thinking needed and reads straightforwardly.

Comment: @J.M. Agreed - neat question, fun burning a cigar and a half pondering differing ways...

Comment: thanks @ciao, this is very instructive!

Comment: @billc: I enjoyed spending some leisure time on it - fun question - I wish there were a way to award bounty to a *question* here - you did a fine job: *Everything* needed to understand the goal is there, examples of work done are there, and what it is your after is there. A textbook example of a good question, IMO.

Comment: Ha!  I actually wasn't sure if it was gonna get flagged for being "too subjective" or something.  I almost didn't post it.  Glad I did!

Comment: @billc, allow me to assure you that the next time somebody asks me "how do I ask a good question?", I will be citing this as one example.

Comment: Could you explain the poisson binomial part? I expect the pb pdf to have a list of probabilities as input (like in my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131347/backtesting-a-probability-of-default-pd-model/131348#131348)) but you have two lists. What are these, and what are a and b?

Comment: [cont'd] Also, given your `Solve`, a and b are complex and can't be probabilities; so, what are they then? @Mr.Wizard do you have a clue?

Comment: hmmm, interesting... These complex probabilities pop-up if you demand that needing one of the two available cupboards is independent of the other. With the given outcomes of {0.6, 0.3, 0.1} such a probability model cannot be gotten in reality, but one can use the complex probabilities in calculations. So, with `a` the probability of needing the first cupboard, and `b` the independent probability of needing the second, we get a*b==0.1 for needing them both and a+b - 2a b == 0.3 for needing one of them (the -2 a b term needed to exclude the overlap between the two)...

Comment: ... Although this leads to a complex solution like {1/20 (5 - I Sqrt[15]), 1/20 (5 + I Sqrt[15])}, this can still be used in the Poisson Binomial calculation. Using [my implementation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131347/backtesting-a-probability-of-default-pd-model/131348#131348): `PoissonBinomialPDF[{1/20 (5 - I Sqrt[15]), 1/20 (5 + I Sqrt[15])}]` ==>{0.6, 0.3, 0.1}, and for 4 chemists: `PoissonBinomialCDF[
 Table[{1/20 (5 - I Sqrt[15]), 1/20 (5 + I Sqrt[15])}, {4}] // 
  Flatten]` ==>{0.1296, 0.3888, 0.6696, 0.864, 0.9585, 0.9909, 0.9987, 0.9999, 1.}

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  - element weights, that is, number of samples for the corresponding probability position.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. My main issue was how a and b could be probabilities given that they were complex. But as I found out as well, complex probabilities work just fine.

Comment: Btw, if your pbpmf2 function does something clever with the weights (other than simply copying the probabilities the given number of times) I'd appreciate it if you could add that as an answer to the question I linked to above.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Re: Complex - yes, just a form of "exotic probability" - questionable if these have any real use, though some QM researchers have proposed their use. Re: Weights - no, nothing "clever" there - not sure there would be a way to get clever....

Comment: @ciao Never mind, I added a weight option to my solution. Speed gains are considerable.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is one way to approach the problem but I am by no means an expert in this area.

```
dd =
 MixtureDistribution[{60, 30, 10}, DiscreteUniformDistribution[{#, #}] & /@ {0, 1, 2}];

N @ Probability[w + x + y + z <= n, # \[Distributed] dd & /@ {w, x, y, z}]
```

$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.1296 & 0.\leq n<1. \\
 0.3888 & 1.\leq n<2. \\
 0.6696 & 2.\leq n<3. \\
 0.864 & 3.\leq n<4. \\
 0.9585 & 4.\leq n<5. \\
 0.9909 & 5.\leq n<6. \\
 0.9987 & 6.\leq n<7. \\
 0.9999 & 7.\leq n<8. \\
 1. & n\geq 8. \\
 0. & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$

Comment: thanks @Mr.Wizard ... much for me to learn from here.

Answer (score 9):

We can encode one chemist's need of fume cupboards with $0.6 + 0.3 c + 0.1 c^2$.  Since they work independently, we may find their simultaneous needs via multiplication:

```
ExpandAll[(0.6 + 0.3 c + 0.1 c^2)^4]
(* Output:  0.1296 + 0.2592 c + 0.2808 c^2 + 0.1944 c^3 + 0.0945 c^4 + 
            0.0324 c^5 + 0.0078 c^6 + 0.0012 c^7 + 0.0001 c^8 *)
```

from which we see several things we know.  No hoods are needed $0.6^4 \approx 0.1296$ of the time.  No more than eight fume cupboards are ever needed (and then only $0.1^4 = 0.0001$ of the time).  Accumulating coefficients from the constants end, we cross 0.95 at $c^4$ and likewise accumulating from the highest degree end we cross 0.05 at $c^4$.  Thus, four cupboards satisfy demand at least 95% of the time.  We can make the computer show us this via

```
Accumulate[CoefficientList[ExpandAll[(0.6 + 0.3 c + 0.1 c^2)^4],c]]
(* Output:  {0.1296, 0.3888, 0.6696, 0.864, 0.9585, 0.9909, 0.9987, 0.9999, 1.} *)
```

Note that this method can be used for mixtures of chemists with different requirements.  So, three chemists requiring 0 or 2 cupboards each half the time and two chemists with the 60%/30%/10% profile of the problem give

```
Accumulate[CoefficientList[ExpandAll[(0.6 + 0.3 c + 0.1 c^2)^2 (0.5 + 0.5 c^2)^3],c]]
(* Output:  {0.045, 0.09, 0.25125, 0.39375, 0.60875, 0.76625, 0.89375, 0.96125, 0.99125, 0.99875, 1.} *)
```

aren't 95% satisfied with fewer than 7 fume cupboards.

We can also mix in additional constrained resources.  Suppose in the original problem that a chemist using one fume cupboard requires six big beakers ($b$) and one using two fume hoods requires four big beakers.  From the encoding $0.6+0.3c b^6 + 0.1 c^2 b^4$, we get

```
Accumulate[CoefficientList[Expand[(0.6 + 0.3 c b^6 + 0.1 c^2 b^4)^4], c]]
(* Output:  Hard to interpret mess.  *)
```

Suppose we decide to have an abundance of beakers.  Then we set $b \rightarrow 1$ and get the above result.  Suppose we can only afford 20 big beakers.  Then $b^{n\_}/;n>20 \rightarrow 0, b^{n\_}/;n<=20 \rightarrow 1$ gives us

```
Accumulate[CoefficientList[Expand[(0.6 + 0.3 c b^6 + 0.1 c^2 b^4)^4], c]/.
    {b^n_ /; n > 20 -> 0, b^n_ /; n <= 20 -> 1}
]
(* Output:  {0.1296, 0.3888, 0.6696, 0.864, 0.9504, 0.972, 0.9798, 0.981, 0.9811}  *)
```

and 4 hoods (barely) meets our 95% criterion.  Repeating with 16 big beakers, we can never reach 95% utilization no matter how many hoods we have.  To find the frontier, we can make a table...

```
TableForm[
    Accumulate[
        Accumulate /@ 
            CoefficientList[Expand[(0.6 + 0.3 c b^6 + 0.1 c^2 b^4)^4], {c, b}]
    ],
    TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 8], Range[0, 24]}
]
(* Output:  Happy to let someone else put this here; I'm not up to that much typing. *)
```

and we discover 95% utilization is hopeless with fewer than 18 big beakers (by running our finger along the last row) or fewer than 4 fume cupboards (by running our finger along the last column).  This is not the generic behaviour.  The generic behaviour gives a tradeoff (more hoods and fewer beakers or vice versa) between resources.  I'm too lazy to adjust this example to show this behaviour.

Edit:
For further reading, see [Generating Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) and [Probability-generating Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function)

Comment: A lovely, clear method.  Note that you do not need `Expand` or `ExpandAll` when using `CoefficientList` however so this can be made cleaner still.

Comment: Nicely done, +1

Comment: Thanks!  This is very cool.  I converted your first two examples to a small table:

`clst = CoefficientList[ExpandAll[(0.6 + 0.3 x + 0.1 x^2)^4], x];
Thread@{Range[0, 8], clst, Accumulate[clst]} // TableForm`

Answer (score 6):

Just a simulation...not as nice as any of the given answers (which I have upvoted...I liked @ciao (rashers) `MultinomialDistribution` transformed {0,1,2}.{a,b,c}.

```
p[n_, s_] := 
 With[{t = 
    Total /@ RandomChoice[{0.6, 0.3, 0.1} -> {0, 1, 2}, {s, 4}]}, 
  N@Total@Boole[Thread[t <= n]]/s]
```

Calculation of probabilities of success with n fume cabinets:

```
With[{r = PowerRange[1000, 1000000]}, 
 TableForm[Table[p[j, #] & /@ r, {j, 0, 7}], 
  TableHeadings -> {Range[0, 7], r}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah - I'd completely neglected simulations, +1