# Does Mathematica have an implementation of the Poisson binomial distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I need to work out the probability of having $k$ successful trials out of a total of $n$ when success probabilities are heterogeneous. This calculation relates to the [Poisson Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). Does Mathematica, or perhaps the Mathstatica add-on, have an implementation for that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mathematica does not know about the *PoissonBinomialDistribution*, but you can use the formula given for the [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution) on Wikipedia:

```
PoissonBinomialDistribution[ plist : { __?NumericQ } ] := With[
    {
      n = Length @ plist,
      c = Exp[(2 I \[Pi])/(Length@plist + 1)]
    }
    ,
    ProbabilityDistribution[
        Re[ 1/(n + 1) Sum[c^(-l k) Product[1 + (c^l - 1) plist[[m]] , {m, 1, n }], {l, 0, n}] ]
        ,
        {k, 0, n, 1}
    ]
 ] /; AllTrue[ plist, 0 <= # <= 1& ]
```

Now we may model a quality control where fault type 1 has a prob of 4% and fault types 2 and 3 have a prob of 7%:

```
dist = PoissonBinomialDistribution[ {0.04, 0.07, 0.07} ];
```

With this we find the probability for 3 faults:

```
Probability[ k == 3, k \[Distributed] dist ]// PercentForm
```

> 0.0196 %

**Update**

Another possibility is to work with [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html). Doing so also allows for symbolic evaluation:

```
PoissonBinomialDistribution::fargs = "Probabilities must be between zero and one";
PoissonBinomialDistribution[ plist : {__?NumericQ | __Symbol } ] := With[
    {
        xList = Table[ Unique["x"], Length @ plist ]
    }
    , 
    If[ Not @ AllTrue[ plist, 0 <= # <= 1 &],
        Return[ Message[PoissonBinomialDistribution::fargs]; $Failed ]
    ];
    TransformedDistribution[ 
        Total @ xList, 
        Thread[ xList \[Distributed] Map[ BernoulliDistribution, plist] ] 
    ]
]

PDF[ PoissonBinomialDistribution[{p1, p2, p3}], x ]
```

[image: Symbolic PDF]

Comment: This produces wildly incorrect results pretty quickly...

Comment: @ciao Will the `TransformedDistribution` solution I just added also produce incorrect results?

Comment: The latter s/b fine, but will get *very* slow with more than a couple dozen probabilities.

Comment: @ciao Indeed, I just tested with a bunch of random numbers: Already with about 15 probs it takes "hours". :-(

Comment: @gwr your original solution is much faster.

Comment: @user120911 You can add `Options` to an implementation of this function and pass a `Method` (e.g. *Automatic*, *FourierTransformation* , *TransformedDistribution* or similar) for switching between implementations.

Comment: As I explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131347/backtesting-a-probability-of-default-pd-model) this solution is quite inadequate. There are much better approaches.

Answer (score 7):

From what it appears you require, the following should suffice:

```
pb = Fold[ListConvolve[##, {1, -1}, 0] &, Transpose[{1 - #, #}]] &;
```

It should provide more accurate results for reasonably sized probability vectors.

As an example, a vector of 100 probabilities:

```
SeedRandom@1234
testps = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100];
```

Timings:

```
r1 = pb@testps; // AbsoluteTiming // First

r2 = Re@PDF[PoissonBinomialDistribution[testps], Range[0, Length@testps]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.0008377
>
> 0.137304

Comparing accuracy with a random sample of the PMFs (`pb` left, `PoissonBinomialDistribution` right. The correctness of `pb` was verified for full PMF):

```
With[{p = RandomSample[Range@100, 10]}, 
  Transpose[{r1[[p]], r2[[p]]}]] // TableForm
```

[image]

You can of course use the same to generate generic results for `n` probabilities,  à la Carl Woll's answer, and then replace probabilities as desired:

```
np = 18;

r1 = Table[p[np, x], {x, 0, np}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

r2 = pb[Array[p, np]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

%%/% // Round

And @@ MapThread[FullSimplify[#1 == #2] &, {r1, r2}]
```

> 504.622
>
> 0.0738808
>
> 6830
>
> True

Same results, but ~1/7000th the time taken. I tried with `np` of 20, gave up waiting, probably 1/20000th the time or so...

Comment: (+1) Very nice. If one uses machine precision numbers and adds `Chop` and `Re` for the Fourier-Transform-Solution the timing can at least be brought down to around 0.034 secs on my machine (which is of course still way off this solution).

Comment: Even faster should be `Threshold` instead of `Chop`...

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is:

```
p[n_, k_] := SeriesCoefficient[Product[1 - (1 - ϵ) p[i], {i, n}], {ϵ, 0, k}]
```

Reproducing gwr's results:

```
Table[p[3, i], {i, 0, 3}] //Simplify //Column //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{l}
>  -(p(1)-1) (p(2)-1) (p(3)-1) \\
>  -2 p(3) p(2)+p(2)+p(3)+p(1) (-2 p(3)+p(2) (3 p(3)-2)+1) \\
>  p(2) p(3)+p(1) (-3 p(3) p(2)+p(2)+p(3)) \\
>  p(1) p(2) p(3) \\
> \end{array}$

Answer (score 4):

I have answered [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131347/backtesting-a-probability-of-default-pd-model) using a full implementation of the Poisson Binomial.